# php: split string with prematch pattern

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I want to split string in array like below example:
these value comes in foreach loop

array('11222S', '11222M', '11222');

I need below output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11222
            [1] => S
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11222
            [1] => M
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11222
            [1] => 
        )

)
```

Please help me how to split it.

I have trying below but not get result:-

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $value, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `preg_match` you can use `preg_split` to slice each string at a position not followed by a digit:

```
$arr = ['11222S', '11222M', '11222'];

$res = array_map(function ($i) { return preg_split('~(?!\d)~', $i, 2); }, $arr);
```

Comment: After little changes it works for me, thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

The pattern can change so try this:

```
$startArray = array('11222S', '11222M', '11222');//but pattern can change
$count = count($startArray);    

$master_array = array(); //hold the split values

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

    $numericPiece = preg_replace("/\D*/", "", $startArray[$i]);
    $alphaPiece = preg_replace("/\d*/", "", $startArray[$i]);

    $master_array[] = array($numericPiece, $alphaPiece);

}
```

Comment: pattern may be different like: `1501GR
1501BLK
1501`

Comment: Edited my solution

Answer (score 0):

> You may try a combination of `foreach()`and `preg_replace()` as shown below. You may also [Quick-Test it Here](https://eval.in/643716).

```
<?php
    $array          = [
                        "11222STV",
                        "11222M",
                        "18742KUM",
                        "11222",
    ];
    $splitArray     = [];
    foreach($array as $k=>$v){
        $tmp            = [];
        $number         = (int)preg_replace("#([A-Z]*?)#",  "", $v);
        $char           = preg_replace("#(\d*?)#",          "", $v);
        $tmp[]          = ($number) ? $number   : "";
        $tmp[]          = ($char)   ? $char     : "";
        $splitArray[]   = $tmp;
    }

    var_dump($splitArray);
```

> The `var_dump()` above yields:

```
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 11222
          1 => string 'STV' (length=3)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 11222
          1 => string 'M' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 18742
          1 => string 'KUM' (length=3)
      3 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 11222
          1 => string '' (length=0)
```